# Get hasPendingWrites in firestore firebase using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently started working on Firestore firebase.
I am trying to get access to the metadata of a particular document to monitor the status of `hasPendingWrites`.
I am using NodeJs as my programming language, and as per the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js), currently accessing metadata is not supported by NodeJs.
Is there any way I can access the metadata using NodeJs?

Thank you

Comment: Which snippet are you referring to in that link? Do you want to access the metadata or getting realtime updates on metadata changes?

Comment: @DanielGomez Thanks for the reply. I am looking into [Events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes). 
I update one of the field in firestore document based on the data I get in nodejs server end point. I would like to know if there is any data currently being written before writing the data to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) snippet says that this is not possible in NodeJS, but it is in C++. The first solution that I'd suggest is to create a [C++ Addon](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/addons.html) for NodeJS in which you'd be able to use the C++ API (So you'd be able to use the same snippet from the docs), and then call this C++ addon from your NodeJS code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Daniel. Does Listening to real time changes before writing solves the concurrency writes to firestore document?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are referring to multiple writes from the same execution, take a look at [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: I am trying to use one of the filed in firestore document as flag to block other end points in a stateless nodejs server. 
I get the status of the field from firestore, if not set I set the flag and proceed. If already set I return. 
Problem that I am facing is there seems to be a delay in updating the field, hence if 2 end points trigger at same time I am not able to acquire lock.

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes that would work I think, as `hasPendingWrites` checks for that from my understanding

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will try if I can do the C++ addon as you suggested in the answer above. 
Any thoughts on how much time it takes to write data to firestore document, I could not find this information in documentation anywhere.

Comment: I don't know either, but I guess it depends mostly on the connection and amount of data on the document. Having a set in stone time is hard having into accoutn that